# How can I use XMLAgg function without an alias in the following SQL example?:

Tags: sql, xml, oracle11g

I have to make XML that complies to a format that I don't control.  It consists of a header called DateRange and then the records from the query.  I can produce XML that almost matches the format except my version has the records in an element, DIV in this example:

```
select
    XMLRoot(
        XMLElement(
            "PayrollAdjustments",
                XMLForest(
                    XMLForest(
                        '2013-09-15' as "From",
                        '2013-09-21' as "To"                    
                    ) as "DateRange",
                    XMLAgg(                  
                        XMLForest(
                            XMLForest(
                                EMPLOYEE as "EmployeeId",
                                STORE AS "StoreNumber",
                                DEPARTMENT AS "Department",
                                WORKCODE AS "AdjustCode",
                                PAYROLL_DATE AS "PayDate",
                                HOURS as "Hours",
                                0 as "Amount"
                            ) AS "PayAdjustment"
                        )   
                    ) AS div
                )
            ),
            VERSION '1.0" encoding="utf-8',
            STANDALONE YES
        ).getClobVal()
from timecard_payroll
where start_date = '2013-09-15'
and end_date = '2013-09-21'
and hours > 0;
```

Here is what the output looks like, as you can see the records are in an element called DIV:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<PayrollAdjustments>
    <DateRange>
        <From>2013-09-15</From>
        <To>2013-09-21</To>
    </DateRange>
    <DIV>
        <PayAdjustment>
            <EmployeeId>262699</EmployeeId>
            <StoreNumber>8159</StoreNumber>
            <Department>1</Department>
            <AdjustCode>91</PayAdjustCode>
            <PayDate>2013-09-16</PayDate>
            <Hours>8.0000</Hours>
            <Amount>0</Amount>
        </PayAdjustment>
        <PayAdjustment>
            <EmployeeId>262916</EmployeeId>
            <StoreNumber>8294</StoreNumber>
            <Department>5</Department>
            <AdjustCode>91</AdjustCode>
            <PayDate>2013-09-19</PayDate>
            <Hours>8.0000</Hours>
            <Amount>0</Amount>
        </PayAdjustment>
    </DIV>  
</PayrollAdjustments>
```

How can I change my query to get rid of the DIV element so that it looks like this?:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<PayrollAdjustments>
    <DateRange>
        <From>2013-09-15</From>
        <To>2013-09-21</To>
    </DateRange>        
    <PayAdjustment>
        <EmployeeId>262699</EmployeeId>
        <StoreNumber>8159</StoreNumber>
        <Department>1</Department>
        <AdjustCode>91</PayAdjustCode>
        <PayDate>2013-09-16</PayDate>
        <Hours>8.0000</Hours>
        <Amount>0</Amount>
    </PayAdjustment>
    <PayAdjustment>
        <EmployeeId>262916</EmployeeId>
        <StoreNumber>8294</StoreNumber>
        <Department>5</Department>
        <AdjustCode>91</AdjustCode>
        <PayDate>2013-09-19</PayDate>
        <Hours>8.0000</Hours>
        <Amount>0</Amount>
    </PayAdjustment>          
</PayrollAdjustments>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `XMLConcat` in conjunction with `XMLSequenceType`:

```
select
    XMLRoot(
        XMLElement(
            "PayrollAdjustments",
                XMLForest(
                    XMLForest(
                        '2013-09-15' as "From",
                        '2013-09-21' as "To"                    
                    ) as "DateRange",
                    XMLConcat(XMLSequenceType(XMLAgg(XMLElement("PayAdjustment",
                            XMLForest(
                                EMPLOYEE as "EmployeeId",
                                STORE AS "StoreNumber",
                                DEPARTMENT AS "Department",
                                WORKCODE AS "AdjustCode",
                                PAYROLL_DATE AS "PayDate",
                                HOURS as "Hours",
                                0 as "Amount"
                            ) AS "PayAdjustment"
                    )))
                )
            ),
            VERSION '1.0" encoding="utf-8',
            STANDALONE YES
        ).getClobVal()
from timecard_payroll
where start_date = '2013-09-15'
and end_date = '2013-09-21'
and hours > 0;
```

Comment: Your example did not exactly work, but the idea of using XMLConcat instead of XMLForest worked, that is I still use XMLForest just not as many of them, what worked was (psuedo code): XMLRoot -> XMLElement -> XMLConcat -> [XMLElement -> XMLForest] , [XMLAgg -> XMLElement -> XMLForest]